# Framework accepts Promises or executor functions

Tags: javascript, api-design, promises

When designing a framework API is it better to have something that accepts `Promise`s  or have executor `function`s and have the framework build the promises when needed.

The [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is defined by the syntax:

```
new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );
```

I have tried both and I am leaning towards having framework users implement a `function(resolve, reject)` to do their data retrievals.  I am thinking that I cannot really reuse a promise once it has been resolved so if I wanted to do a reload of the data I would need to re-execute the executor function.

Comment: Re-evaluate which function?

Comment: executor function (updated)

Comment: Which function is the executor function? I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you won't be actually defining the `Promise` function within your API; i.e. you will be using the implementation already defined in JavaScript.

In saying that, [MDN states that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

> The Promise object is used for asynchronous computations. A Promise represents a value which may be available now, or in the future, or never.
>
> ...
>
> A pending promise can either be fulfilled with a value, or rejected with a reason (error).  When either of these options happen, the associated handlers queued up by a promise's **then** method are called.

Here we can see that a promise is primarily interacted with through it's *then* method, so as for deciding which implementation to choose it doesn't matter as long as the fulfillment/rejection can be obtained.

> I am thinking that I cannot really reuse a promise once it has been resolved so if I wanted to do a reload of the data I would need to re-execute the executor function.

The value of a promise is a yet to be determined thing, but when it is it can be accessed just like any other variable. [from MDN `Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

> The Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value. If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value.

So, for example,

```
var thisPromise = somePromise();

//fulfilled or rejected
thisPromise.then(function(value) {
 console.log("this is the value: "+value);
}).catch(function(reason) {
 console.log("was rejected with reason: "+reason);
});

//... some code later assuming you don't change thisPromise

thisPromise.then(function(value) {
 console.log("this is the same value as before: "+value);
}).catch(function(reason) {
 console.log("was rejected with reason: "+reason);
});
```

If by reload data you mean that the data retrieved by the promise needs to be updated, then yes it will need to be re-executed to retrieve new data.